# Haskell catch function without parameters

Tags: function, haskell, parameters

As an exercise working on own module for generating HTML, JS etc. If I got:

```
putHtml (attrib, input) | attrib == "setTitle" = setTitle input
```

and I were to call this without params like: `putHtml` the compiler will obviously complain. Since I am a beginner and Haskell has proven to be overwhelming a little, I am confused about how to catch functions with omitted params.

Comment: You can't 'catch' compiler errors. When a compiled language fails to compile, there's nothing that will run, so no exceptions to catch. You must address compiler errors by writing the code in such a way that the errors disappear.

Comment: That is a very clear answer, so back to the code then. Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, this definition would be better written as `putHtml ("setTitle", input) = setTitle input`